# Python 3: get 2nd to last index of occurrence in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string `abcdabababcebc` How do I get the index of the second-to-last occurrence of `b`? I searched and found rfind() but that doesn't work since it's the last index and not the second-to-last.

I am using Python 3.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted.

Comment: Did you look at all three parameters to [`str.rfind`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind), or read the description? That's not explaining a downvote (I don't know who downvoted it or why); I'm curious where you "searched and found rfind()" that didn't have that info, because it really should be fixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> def find_second_last(text, pattern):
...   return text.rfind(pattern, 0, text.rfind(pattern))
... 
>>> find_second_last("abracadabra", "a")
7
```

This uses the optional start and end parameters to look for the second occurrence after the first occurrence has been found.

Note: This does not do any sort of sanity checking, and will blow up if there are not at least 2 occurrences of pattern in the text.

Comment: +1, because I think this is better than copying most of the string just to search the copy (in cases where it matters).

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> s = "abcdabababcebc"
>>> s[:s.rfind("b")].rfind("b")
9
```

Answer (score 11):

Enumerate all the indices and choose the one you want

```
In [19]: mystr = "abcdabababcebc"

In [20]: inds = [i for i,c in enumerate(mystr) if c=='b']

In [21]: inds
Out[21]: [1, 5, 7, 9, 12]

In [22]: inds[-2]
Out[22]: 9
```

Comment: +1 for being flexible (e.g., what if you want to find the Nth last?), and for it being blatantly obvious how it works. Of course it's not a great solution if `mystr` is huge and/or has lots of copies of `'b'` (in which case see MAK's solution), but usually that won't matter.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, this does use linear space in the worst case

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that is higher space-complexity

Comment: It's better to operate directly on the string instead of using indexes if possible with things like rfind and find, and sometimes even re.